# Meaning of < and > in JavaScript export or function definitions

Tags: javascript

In javascript codes, I see statements like this:

```
export default mongoose.model<UserInterface & mongoose.Document>('User', UserSchema)
```

this example is taken from repo:
https://github.com/santiq/nodejs-auth.git

It would be great if someone could explain what <UserInterface & mongoose.Document> means?
You can find similar statements, i.e. `Promise<any>` few times in the same repo.
It is not the first time I see this kind of statement and I cannot find any explanation of it. Since I am learning JavaScript very actively it is important for me to understand advanced syntax and any "ninja" codes.

Thanks in advance
Jo

Comment: That's not JavaScript, that's TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

That's not JavaScript, that's TypeScript.

- The `<` and `>` delimit type-parameter arguments.
- The `&` denotes an [Intersection Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).

In this case, it's declaring that the module's default exported item is a `model` object that concerns *any* object that has members belonging to both `UserInterface` and `Document` simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

That is great help guys!
Great thanks!
I didn't expected that answer. I went through internet back and forth with no answer for my question simply because I did not consider that it could be anything else than JS.

Thanks a million
Jo